# Amazon AWS Images are not showing?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, heroku

I am trying to add images to work in my app. I have installed the Amazon AWS SDK gem and setup the environments variables but when i create an image tag the image is not showing in Heroku. Heres my code

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 3):

When I open https://s3.amazonaws.com/skilllzy/134H.jpg in my browser, I get:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>CA4454AACA61F45E</RequestId>
<HostId>
5fAq4OGDrjMUD9b012vBi495TizgPsrkHQh3ZFZYdzcv2LJLuY48F/Ug1KzEQV5iArlt0DY1Ixg=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

This indicates either a) you have not configured the bucket as a static website or b) you do not have the correct permissions on that bucket to allow public accesss.

Please review [Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) and [Permissions Required for Website Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html) to make sure you have properly configured the bucket for public http access.

Comment: yep. the "little lock" near the link tells us that the file is not public -> Access Denied